# How do I export Excel as PDF with bookmarks created from sheets name in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, bookmarks

I'd like to save the spreadsheet to PDF and create bookmarks with the Sheet names.

My code is generating the PDF file from the excel perfectly, but is not creating bookmarks.

```
Sub MacroCreateExcelToPDF()
    'Select ALL Sheets in the excel to generate the PDF
    Worksheets.Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:R39").Select

    'Generate EXCEL in PDF file
    Dim myfile As Variant
    Dim strfile As String
    Dim strPath As String

    strfile = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsx", "_")
    strPath = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Path, "Input", "Output")
    strfile = strfile & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") & ".pdf"
    strfile = strPath & "\" & strfile

    myfile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strfile, _
    FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
    Title:="Select Folder and File Name to Save as PDF")


    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    myfile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

--beckerc73, experiencing the same issue, added:
When I run the Export as PDF from the File menu manually, Excel adds bookmarks. However, the ExportAsFixedFormat method in VBA does not.

A simple solution might be similar to the "CreateBookmarks" parameter of the Word ExportAsFixedFormat method, but I don't see it documented for Excel.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As this is not a free code-writing service, can you help us to know what you have tried so far in order to add the bookmarks? What specifically isn't working in your attempt?

Comment: Refer https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1861137 and https://forums.adobe.com/message/2253395#2253395

Comment: @Jitendra, thank you for the documentation that you add, this will help me a lot.